# Java inheritance: same method of different objects

Tags: java, inheritance

say I have the following simple construct:

```
public abstract class Geometry {
   ...
}

public class TriangleGeo extends Geometry {
   Triangle triangle;
}

public class RectangleGeo extends Geometry {
   Rectangle rectangle;
}

public class Rectangle {
   private size;
}

public class Triangle {
   private size;
}
```

I now have two methods:

```
public void calcSizeOfRect(Rectangle rect){
  System.out.println(rect.size);
}

public void calcSizeOfTria(Triangle tria){
  System.out.println(tria.size);
}
```

What I really want to have is just one calcSize-method for both objects. Because really the methods do 1:1 the same, and will only touch common properties.

The only possible way I could think to solve this is to move the color variable into the Geometry class. Do you perhaps know another approach to this? Because the refactoring would be a lot of work..

Using Java 9 if that matters.

Comment: Are the classes `Rectangle` and `Rectangle` and `Triangle` and `Triangle` located in the same package? If not then you will have a compile time error?

Comment: Why do you have 2 `Rectangle` and `Triangle` classes? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, put an abstract method named `calcSize()` in the `abstract class Geometry` and then override it in it's children classes according to your requirements.

Or

Create an interface called `2DShapes` (because it makes more sense, also use the name `area` and not `size`, makes more sense) and have the method `calcSize()` inside that. Then implement that interface for whatever class you want to like in the above approach.
You need [polymorphism](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-guide-to-polymorphism-in-java/) (to be precise, Dynamic Polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

All you will need to do is add the below method

```
public void calcSize(Geometry geometry) {
    // Implementation code
}
```

Since both the `Triangle` and `Rectangle` inherit from `Geometry` you can create a method that accepts an instance of `Geometry`.

If the method `calcSize` is going to be part of the `Geometry` class you can even just do

```
public void calcSize() {
    // Implementation Code
}
```

You will be able to this because in theory you should potentially already have the details to calculate the size. This however all depends on other facts in your implementation.

The other option would be to implement an `interface`, see [@WJS's answer for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753790/java-inheritance-same-method-of-different-objects/58753935#58753935)

Comment: But wait, I cannot access the object's size parameter this way. The size attribute is not part of the parent Geometry class. That's the core of my problem:/

Comment: @CoffeeCups All you'd need to do is make it part of the `Geometry` class. If all classes that inherit from `Geometry` should have a `size` property then really it should be in the `Geometry` class. I'd even say that the `Geometry` constructor should accept `size` as a parameter. And then in any subclass of `Geometry` you should enforce that class provides a `size` parameter in their constructors as well which will get passed up into the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would to declare an `Interface` for each type.

```java
interface BasicShape {
    public double getArea();
    public Color getColor ();
}

class Triangle implements BasicShape {
   double area;
   Color color;
   Triangle (int base, int height, Color color) {
      area = .5*base*height;
      this.color = color;
   }
   public Color getColor() {
       return color;
   }
   public double getArea() {
      return area;
   }

}
```

Then for each type, implement the appropriate code.

Comment: I do like the idea of an interface however what you have will not work and will throw errors. You cannot have `public int area() { }`, unless you use the default keyword like `default int area() { // Implementation code }` you will get errors because `interfaces cannot have implementation code with that `default` keyword. Also its `interface` not `Interface`. I have -1'd however I will remove if you correct your code.

Comment: I corrected it before you posted. That's the problem with writing on the fly.

Comment: Removed as promised, didn't want to sound petty; so sorry if I did as it was such a small thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SolutionGeometry {

    public static void calcSiz(Geometry geo){
         System.out.println(geo.size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Triangle a = new Triangle();
        a.size = 6;
        calcSiz(a);
        Rectangle b = new Rectangle();
        b.size = 6;
        calcSiz(b);
    }
}

abstract class Geometry {
   int size;
   private int color;
}

class Triangle extends Geometry {

}

class Rectangle extends Geometry { 

}
```

Comment: What? Why would they have the `calcSize` method outside of the `Geometry` class?